# How can I convert pygame to exe?

Tags: python, pygame

Recently, I made a pygame game. I want to show it to my friends. But unfortunately, I cant make an executable file, only a `.py` file. I have tried to use tools such as `py2exe` which might not support Python 3.6 and `pyinstaller`. I think `pyinstaller` may be useful, and I can also make an exe successfully but it didn't work at all. It just showed it couldn't open the sound file which is already in the same file.

I have tried two ways to load files firstly, just load the path then the exe converted shows it can't open the file which is already in the same path with the exe.

Secondly, I use the `os.path` which the exe showed it cant open `...../temp/...` which is a long path but my computer doesn't have this folder at all.

I am a new guy to learn python. I have searched for a day and can't make it work. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on writing a working game. Your problem is clear, but it's not the kind of question that's easily answered, or the type of question that StackOverflow is typically for. You should probably try writing a simpler script that illustrates the problem - perhaps you'll run into a solution yourself. Otherwise, post the simpler script that you can't get to work here, with instructions on what you did and what causes the problem. Both py2exe and pyinstaller could be good solutions, if you can get them to work.

Comment: Are you using ogg format for sound?

Comment: It looks like a more specific problem you're having is "How to load files in executables built with PyInstaller?" If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215253/7675174) provides a thorough example. If you have specific problems following that answer, please edit this question or ask another to get further assistance. Additionally, reading read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you create questions that are more likely to be answered helpfully.

Comment: Today, I have a same question like you. So, I researched and saw a video guide on Youtube with convert pygame to .exe. Hope can help anyone, who have same this problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTxaran0Cig
Anyway, this video made from Jan 2020, so at the time this question appear we don't have a clear answer

Answer (score 32):

I'm just a scripting hack, and an idiot when it comes to command line tools. But I REALLY wanted to package up my python game into a Windows executable. I wrestled with pyinstaller for days, and read all of the threads of others who are also trying to figure it out, and I also read all the pyinstaller docs several times. No one solution worked for me, but after much trial and error I finally stumbled onto a recipe for success and want to share it in case there are other pygame developers out there banging their heads against this. The solution contains bits and pieces of several threads.

How to create a single file exe of a multi-file python pygame with several asset directories using pyinstaller on Windows:

First, install pyinstaller.

Open Windows Command Prompt, type:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Make a python game. Say the main game file is called main_game_script.py, located in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\python\game_dir
```

Add this function to main_game_script.py. Make sure to import os and sys. (I never would have figured out on my own that I needed to add this function to my game, but it works, so thanks to whoever posted it in some other thread)

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

To load images into game, call that function, like such:

```
asset_url = resource_path('assets/chars/hero.png')
hero_asset = pygame.image.load(asset_url)
```

When your game is ready to be wrapped in an EXE, open Windows Command Prompt. Go to the main game directory and type:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main_game_script.py --collect-data assets/chars --collect-data assets/tiles --collect-data assets/fonts
```

It'll look like this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\python\game_dir>pyinstaller --onefile main_game_script.py  --collect-data assets/chars --collect-data assets/tiles --collect-data assets/fonts
```

This will create four important items:

```
- a main_game_script.spec file in the game_dir
- a 'build' dir in the game_dir
- a 'dist' directory in the game_dir
- a main_game_script.exe will be created in the 'dist' directory.
```

Running the command spits out a ton of warnings and logs. I don't know what it all means. But as long as the final output line says success, you're probably good.

If your exe is still not working: First, you must modify the .spec file (which now exists in the game_dir) to add the needed game asset paths to the exe:

Open the main_game_script.spec file in notepad or whatever.
Replace the empty datas[] list with asset directory paths like such (using tuples!):

```
datas=[('assets/chars/*','assets/chars'),('assets/tiles/*.png','assets/tiles'),('assets/fonts/*','assets/fonts')],
```

The first value of each tuple is the actual file names you want to import.
The second value is the relative path from you main_game_script.py
The syntax and paths must be perfect, or it won't work and may not throw an error

Save and close the 'main_game_script.spec' file. Return to your windows command prompt. Type:

```
pyinstaller main_game_script.spec
```

Like this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\python\game_dir>pyinstaller main_game_script.spec
```

This somehow embeds the asset dir paths into the exe that you've already built

After all this (which only takes a couple minutes after you've done it 100 times), you finally have a single file EXE of your python game that includes all of the game assets. If you've done everything right, double click on the EXE to play your python game.

Note: getting it right the first time took me a couple days. I started with a simple test_game_script.py with minimal code and iterated methodically, adding more asset paths and complexity with each iteration so I could isolate what was broken and why. If your game isn't converting to EXE properly, start with a simple 5 line game script with one asset and slowly build on it until you have a pipeline that works, THEN apply that functioning asset pipeline your ACTUAL game. Otherwise isolating the problem will be impossible.

Comment: I tried these steps on both a mac and a window computer, and I keep getting this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
[68210] Failed to execute script game

Comment: This answer is gold, thank you for sharing! To hide the console on Windows and show only your game window, this command worked for me: `pyinstaller --onefile game.py --windowed` (replace `game.py` with your game file name).

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add `--hidden-import pygame`**.
Something like:
`python -m PyInstaller <options> xxx.py --hidden-import pygame`
**2. Hack the pygame stdout.**
If you used the option `-w`, it will fail because of the (annoying) version output of pygame.
Workaround:

```py
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    import pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem and spent days looking through google. Today finally I realised what was the problem.
Before trying to convert it, remember to install Pygame via the Terminal as well. Just type in "pip install pygame"

Answer (score 1):

@Blue Botic answer above works like a charm! Thank you!

I added the "--noconsole" parameter in the below command to get rid of the console and only show the game's main window:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main_game_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with cx_freeze

```
pip install cx_freeze
```

You will need to create a setup.py file to help cx_freeze build the executable

```
import cx_Freeze

# base = "Win32GUI" allows your application to open without a console window
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('my_example_app.py', base = "Win32GUI")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "My Example Exe App",
    options = {"build_exe" : 
        {"packages" : ["pygame"], "include_files" : ['example_folder_with_files/', 'ExampleFont.ttf', 'example_text_file.txt']}},
    executables = executables
)
```

Be sure to add **your** packages, fonts, or files to the script and any additional files that your app needs to the setup.

Finally you need to run your setup.py script

```
python setup.py build
```

or if you want cx_freeze to create an installer for you

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

Sentdex has a nice walkthrough on his website
[pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-pygame-executable-cx_freeze/)

Answer (score 1):

With PyInstaller it's possible without editing the .spec file, using the argument --collect-data NAME_ASSET_FOLDER

```
pyinstaller main_game_script.py --onefile --windowed --collect-data assets/chars --collect-data assets/tiles --collect-data assets/fonts
```