# How to make exe of pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've finished developing my game in pygame and I want to make a exe of it so I can share it. I tried using cx_Freeze for making exe but in that tutorial he just added only single image and I was confused how I must add these many sprites in a single line I followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIWqt6NICrw&t=49s

In this tutorial he adds only single image file since his game is too small. So I tried different ways. I tried this method - [How can I convert pygame to exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210392/how-can-i-convert-pygame-to-exe) But its too complex and when I try to perform it I get so many syntax error (I tried that method 10 times)

All I can see there is only one way left to develop exe of my pygame using cx_Freeze but I don't know how to do so. And I'm using python3 (ver:3.7.3)

Can anyone explain me step by step how to make game using cx_Freeze (please also let me know how to add multiple images since i got so many images (sprites) each for different enemies and hero)

Comment: Something like this? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Im talking about pygame not python script- this method won't work here

Comment: Pygame is just a library that you can include in your python script. Perhaps elaborate why that method wont work?

Comment: pygame is a python library so this will work... maybe you have to configure a bit more but python is python. I succesfully used py2exe for Python GUIs made with Qt using third party libraries multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered a few times before, converting a pygame to exe is same as converting other python gui applications.

a link to one of the previous questions:
[Create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python)

A addition to the Aakash Mehta's answer, relating to this link: https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-pygame-executable-cx_freeze/

If you want to add more files, you need to add them to the include list:

```
cx_Freeze.setup(
name="A bit Racey",
options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                       "include_files":["racecar.png", "add_files.png", "one_more.png"]}}, # This line
executables = executables)
```

Comment: I got so many images - is there any shortcut to import those images?

Comment: you can use the os module, put all images in one folder and just loop through all names of the images in that folder. Or use this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079268/how-can-i-include-a-folder-with-cx-freeze

Comment: can you explan me how to do it by first method please

Comment: Heres a tutorial on it:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir
If my answer is satisfactory please accept my answer.

Comment: I figured it out how to use os.path but im still not able to make exe using cx_Freeze

Comment: if there is any other way then let me know please

Comment: look through the first link I posted.

Comment: Everything is going good but after I make exe using cx_Freeze and try to open it - it opens and closes CMD. I've been searching for fix everywhere but no luck - do you have any way to fix it?

Comment: i tried running that exe by using CMD and I get error - Failed to execute script mygame and its pointing to pygame.error: Couldn't open LongBGx5.png but when i run game using pycharm it runs properly without any errors

Comment: Sound like another problem, open up another issue and add that log when asking a question. As it seems my answer was satisfactory, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller is also being used to make exe, I don't know if it will help in your case or not.

Comment: I tried Pyinstaller but when i start exe - it opens cmd and gets closed quciky

Answer (score 0):

According to this website
https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-pygame-executable-cx_freeze/
You can use a module called cx_Freeze which is similar to py2exe.
Some of the steps are similar to py2exe
And all the instructions are on the website.

Comment: that person developed a simple game which contain only one image file, he didn't explained what to do if there are multiple image files each for character.