# How can I create a executable from a game written in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, executable

I have written a game with Python3 using Pygame module. Now I want to create an **executable** of the game for **Mac Os** so that I can distribute it.

Comment: try this https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this and report if it works:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

*navigate to project directory*

```
pyinstaller --onefile insertfilenamehere.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been anwsered here : [How can I convert pygame to exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210392/how-can-i-convert-pygame-to-exe)

But basically what you want to do is :

1 - Install pyinstaller :

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

2 - Deal with static assets such as images with this code :

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Then to load the images in the game you call your function

```
asset_url = resource_path('assets/chars/hero.png')
hero_asset = pygame.image.load(asset_url)
```

3 - Finally, you can create an executable from your .py file by typing the following in a CMD inside of your game directory :

```
pyinstaller --onefile main_game_script.py
```